# I get an error on customer or product grid when I sort by ID or apply filter on product ,customer , content->block , content->page then show error

Tags: magento2

I get an error when I am trying to sort on the basis of ID are apply filter on product ,customer , content->block , content->page  then this error pops up

**Error:Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state**

I got some solutions that asked me to clear the UI_bookmark table. This however temporarily solved the problem and let the page load.

It’s not however the solution as when I did the action again it causes the same issue all over again

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some kind of screen shot or exact flow of the error?

Comment: try to reindex and then flush the  cache

Comment: Hi Mayur,                                                                                                                              
I have added screenshot into question